# Base64 wrapped encoder to write to TCP stream returns garbled bytes

Tags: java, kotlin, tcp, base64, outputstream

I am trying to stream base64 encoded content to an output stream from a kotlin client over TCP to a python server.  When I read on the python side, I do not have a base64 encoded result.  Here is the code:

```
private val o = ObjectMapper().disable(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET)
fun encode(cmdBodyRequest: ClientRequest, output: OutputStream) {
    output.write("""{"req":"${cmdBodyRequest.req}","work_def":"""".toByteArray())
    val wrappedOutputStream = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(output)
    o.writeValue(wrappedOutputStream, mapOf("hello" to "world"))
    wrappedOutputStream.close()
    output.write("\"}".toByteArray())
    output.write("\n".toByteArray())
}
```

On the python server side I am simply reading a line in from the stream reader.  My result looks like this:

```
{"req":"549ebd95-41cb-46f1-93fa-dc355f70f16a","work_def":"\x00\x00\x00I\x00\x00\x00m\x00\x00\x00U\x00\x00\x00y\x00\x00\x00a\x00\x00\x00G\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00i\x00\x00\x00R\x00\x00\x003\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x002\x00\x00\x00U\x00\x00\x00F\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00k\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00m\x00\x00\x00N\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00G\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00m\x00\x00\x00U\x00\x00\x00T\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x009"}\n'
```

My goal is to base64 encode the work_def which can be a very large nested json structure (I've just been using a mapOf("hello" to "world") for testing purposes) for the sake of preventing python from decoding it into a dict which I don't want it to do.  It is expensive and the server doesn't need to know the contents of the work_def, it just needs to pass on the request to another client.  I also want to avoid base64 encoding in memory on the client side as I don't want to use up additional bytes for a copy of the base64 encoded object.  I want to have the base64 encoding performed on the output stream to prevent additional overhead.

Any help on what I am doing wrong or how this can be achieved would be much appreciated.

Comment: The code you shared works for me. Have you tried using a ByteArrayOutputStream to capture the output and inspect it?

Comment: Incidentally, beware of embedding `cmdBodyRequest.req` directly in your JSON, unless you are _absolutely certain_ it can never contain a quotation mark or a backslash, or any other character that would invalidate the JSON. You might want to consider using your ObjectMapper to convert it to a JSON string, and embedding that instead.

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is the code that generates this output? I ask because the string you got is actually `{hello=world}`, but encoded with base64 twice and with some additional garbage. Are you sure this is not from testing or experimenting with the code?